# Writing data as JSON array with Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have to write data from Spark Structure streaming as JSON Array, I have tried using below code:

```
df.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value").toJSON
```

which returns me DataSet[String], but unable to write as JSON Array.

Current Output:

```
{"name":"test","id":"id"}
{"name":"test1","id":"id1"}
```

Expected Output:

```
[{"name":"test","id":"id"},{"name":"test1","id":"id1"}]
```

**Edit (moving comments into question):**

After using proposed `collect_list` method I am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;
```

Then I tried something like this -

```
withColumn("timestamp", unix_timestamp(col("event_epoch"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa")) .withWatermark("event_epoch", "1 minutes") .groupBy(col("event_epoch")) .agg(max(col("event_epoch")).alias("timestamp"))
```

But I don't want to add a new column.

Comment: @mike I am ok to convert the whole batch to a single array and write to file and Kafka.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the SQL built-in function [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#collect_list) for this. This function collects and returns a set of non-unique elements (compared to `collect_set` which returns only unique elements).

From the source code for [collect_list](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L310) you will see that this is an aggregation function. Based on the requirements given in the Structured Streaming Programming Guide on [Output Modes](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes) it is highlighted that the output modes "complete" and "updated" are supported for aggregations without a watermark.

[image]

As I understand from your comments, you do not wish to add watermark and new columns. Also, the error you are facing

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark;
```

reminds you to not use the output mode "append".

In the comments, you have mentioned that you plan to produce the results into a Kafka message. One big JSON Array as one Kafka value. The complete code could look like

```scala
val df = spark.readStream
  .[...] // in my test I am reading from Kafka source
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING) as key", "CAST(value AS STRING) as value", "offset", "partition")
  // do not forget to convert you data into a String before writing to Kafka
  .selectExpr("CAST(collect_list(to_json(struct(*))) AS STRING) AS value")

df.writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .outputMode("complete")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "test")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/path/to/sparkCheckpoint")
  .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10000))
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

Given the key/value pairs (k1,v1), (k2,v2), and (k3,v3) as inputs you will get a value in the Kafka topic that contains all selected data as a JSON Array:

```
[{"key":"k1","value":"v1","offset":7,"partition":0}, {"key":"k2","value":"v2","offset":8,"partition":0}, {"key":"k3","value":"v3","offset":9,"partition":0}]
```

Tested with Spark 3.0.1 and Kafka 2.5.0.

Comment: Thanks, Mike! It works with Kafka but not to file.